# Parsing free-form salary information

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm trying to parse salary information from a free-form source. I'd like to be able to store the parsed info in a standard format after parsing. There are a number of permutations that I expect to encounter based on experience.

Here's an example of some of the cases I expect:

```
$10/hr,
$10.00/hr,
$10 per hour,
$10 per hr,
$10.00 per hour,
$10.00 per hr,
10$/hr,
10$/hour,
10.00$/hr,
10.00$/hour
```

I could go on and on but I think you get the idea.

Generalized, the formats I'm expecting can be explained like so:

**[curr][amount[.xx]][[k][,000]][curr][-][per][-][timeframe]**

- [**curr**] can be any currency symbol, can either appear before or after amount, but not both. Optional
- [**amount**] can be int or float, the .xx is optional and can either be .x or .xx. Mandatory
- [**[k][,000]**] indicates amount = amount * 1000. Optional
- [**-**] separator can either be a space or a dash. Optional
- [**per**] can either be "per" or "/". Mandatory
- [**timeframe**] can be: year, yr, hour, hr. Mandatory

I definitely suspect that I'll need to use some sort of regex here, but I have no experience at all implementing regex and frankly, it confuses me a bit. I'm not looking for someone to solve this problem for me, but if you can help push me off into the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Ultimately, I'd like to store the results like:

```
Class Salary():
    float hourly_pay
    String pay_type #hourly or salary
```

Comment: A push in the right direction would be to start playing around with learning regex

Answer (score 0):

This snippet shows something that accomplishes something close to what I was looking for. It's certainly not elegant, but it works.

This is my first regex ever, any suggestions on how to improve this?

[https://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/44](https://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/43)